# Angular 2 getting components to listen to one another

Tags: angular

I have a navigation component that I want to be either shown or hidden based on whether or not a user is signed in. To do this, I added a localStorage to confirm that a user is signed in. However, my navigation component only listens to this during `OnInit`.

How might I go about having one component listen to changes from another? In this case, having navigation respond to the signin component's function `onlogin`.

**navigation.component.ts**

```
export class NavigationComponent implements OnInit {
private navshow: boolean;
if (localStorage.getItem('confirmo')){ this.navshow = true; }
}
```

**signin.component.ts**

```
export class SigninClass {
onlogin(){
localStorage.setItem('confirmo', 'verdad');  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could track something onChanges or use the event methodology to 'shout' out that a change has occurred.

So create a singleton service. Have a emitting method. Pick up the service in your other components and subscribe to it.

i.e

Service

```
export class MessageInformation{
    constructor(public name: string, public details: string, public extra?: any[]){

    }
}

@Injectable()
export class MessagingService {
public parentFrameChangeEvent: EventEmitter<MessageInformation>;

constructor(){
    this.parentFrameChangeEvent = new EventEmitter<MessageInformation>();
}

public sendMessage(message: MessageInformation): void{
    this.parentFrameChangeEvent.emit(message);
}
```

}

then inject into your calling constructor and use as so

```
  var reloadMessage: MessageInformation = { name: "reload", details: "forcereload", extra: tabIdArray };
        this.messaging.sendMessage(reloadMessage);
```

(note you dont need the MessageInformation which is just an internal class I use to allow extra information to be passed through)

then inject the same singleton service in any destination components and subscribe

```
this.messenger.parentFrameChangeEvent.subscribe(message => this.reloadData(message));
```

In that method you then do all your work on the login event

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at the following link.  You can use observable's and a shared service to achieve this.

[Angular.io Component Interaction using a Service](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service)